# Crawled properties not created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawled-property

I've this custom field :

```
<Field ID="{DDD9E7FE-29CE-4902-B9EB-8964429C05D2}" StaticName="TEST_NEWS" Name="TEST_NEWS" DisplayName="News" Type="Note" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" NumLines="6" Group="Colonnes TEST" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"/>
```

I've bind the field with a content type named "Article" and I've create a page with this content type and a content. When I start a full crawl, the crawl properties for this field is not created. I've tried to reset the index and start another crawl but nothing.

Do you have an idea of what happened?

Edit :
It's a site column and it's linked to a custom content type.

Comment: Is this a site column? and associate to Content type?

Answer (score -1):

It works after a restart of the server.